# При уменьшении браузера исчезает правая часть сайта

Tags: html, css

Файл html:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 96px;
  min-width: 900px;
  background: green;
}
.podheader {
  height: 96px;
  width: 981px;
  margin-left: 459px;
  background: #050505;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="podheader"></div>
</div>
```

При уменьшении окна браузера почему-то пропадает правая часть шапки сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Она не пропадает. Страница скроллится горизонтально.

Comment: ну вот погляньте что у вас ! вы родителю задали минимальный размер 900 рх а потомку 981 рх  и ещё сдвинули его на 459 рх в право ! потому и появился у вас скролл - потомок не может быть больше родителя - установите потомку ширину в % к примеру 90% но не двигайте его на 459рх а выравняйте по центру а внутри потомка создайде элемент и его можно сдвинуть куда угодно но опять в пределах а можно отпозиционировать в правом углу

Answer (score 2):

Задавайте ширину в процентах, тогда скролл появляться не будет, и ничего у вас не пропадет !